# How to update datalist for dynamic auto-completion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, datalist

I am using a datalist for having auto-completion in an input text.
I initialize it well, but I would like to update dynamically my source and my suggestions.

Do you know how to do something like this?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title" list="suggestionList" ng-change="changeIsRaised()">
<datalist id="suggestionList">
    <option data-ng-repeat="ttl in titles" value="{{ttl}}">
</datalist>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.titles = ["Action Comics", "Detective Comics", "Superman", "Fantastic Four", "Amazing Spider-Man"];

$scope.changeIsRaised = function() {
    if ($scope.title == "ch") {
        var newSrc = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
        $scope.titles = newSrc;

    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? It looks like it should work.

Comment: no it does not  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 'nicolas' listed twice causing a `ng-repeat` error. You could add a `track by $index` to fix it, but probably you should just remove the duplicate.

```js
function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.titles = ["Action Comics", "Detective Comics", "Superman", "Fantastic Four", "Amazing Spider-Man"];

  $scope.changeIsRaised = function() {
    if ($scope.title == "ch") {
      var newSrc = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "joseph"];
      $scope.titles = newSrc;

    }
  }
}
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', ctrl);
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="title" list="suggestionList" ng-change="changeIsRaised()">
    <datalist id="suggestionList">
      <option data-ng-repeat="ttl in titles" value="{{ttl}}">
    </datalist>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```